# How to include one division to other pages in angular js application?

Tags: html, angularjs

In my angularjs application I have one page order-details, in that there are two divisions, leftwrapper and writewrapper. I need left wrapper to other pages, how to include that division to other pages?

### order-details

[image: order-details]

In this leftwrapper means My acount section needed in this below page.

[image: security]

### order-details.html

```
<div id="manage" class="page-layout simple tabbed">

<!-- HEADER -->
<div class="header md-accent-bg" layout="row" layout-align="start center">
     <div class="title">
        <span class="md-display-1 font-weight-300">Your Orders!</span>
     </div>
</div>

<md-content layout-padding> 
    <div class="innerContent">
    
        <div class="leftWrapper">
            <div>                   
                <h1>My Account</h1>
                <div class="leftContent">
                <nav class="{{active}}" ng-click="$event.preventDefault()">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div class="userInfo">
                                <div class="userImage">
                                    <img md-menu-align-target class="avatar" src="assets/images/avatars/profile.jpg">
                                </div>
                                <div class="userName">
                                    <span style="font-size:15px;">{{vm.name}}</span><br>
                                    <span style="font-size:13px; color:#ccc">{{vm.email}}</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <hr></hr>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <i class="iconLeft">
                                 <md-icon md-font-icon="icon-cart" class="icon"></md-icon>
                            </i> ORDERS <br>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="orders" ms-nav-button ui-sref="app.order-details" md-ink-ripple>
                                        <span class="ms-nav-label" >Orders</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <hr></hr>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <i class="iconLeft">
                                  <md-icon md-font-icon="icon-account" class="icon"></md-icon>
                            </i> PROFILE <br>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="address" ms-nav-button ui-sref="app.personal-details" md-ink-ripple>
                                        <span class="ms-nav-label" >Saved Address</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="wishlist" ms-nav-button ui-sref="app.wishlist" md-ink-ripple>
                                        <span class="ms-nav-label" >Wishlist</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="contributions" ms-nav-button ui-sref="app.manage-contributor" md-ink-ripple>
                                        <span class="ms-nav-label" >Manage Contributions</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="contributions" ms-nav-button ui-sref="app.security" md-ink-ripple>
                                        <span class="ms-nav-label" >Security</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="contributions" ms-nav-button ui-sref="app.message" md-ink-ripple>
                                        <span class="ms-nav-label" >Message to Guest</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="contributions" ms-nav-button ui-sref="app.invitation" md-ink-ripple>
                                        <span class="ms-nav-label" >Invitation Inserts</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <hr></hr>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <i class="iconLeft">
                                  <md-icon md-font-icon="icon-cake" class="icon"></md-icon>
                            </i> Occassion <br>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="occassion" ng-click="vm.popUpDialog()" md-ink-ripple style="cursor:pointer">
                                        <span class="ms-nav-label" >Add Occassion</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <hr></hr>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <i class="iconLeft">
                                  <md-icon md-font-icon="icon-email" class="icon"></md-icon>
                            </i> TELEGRAM <br>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="telegram" ms-nav-button ui-sref="app.telegram-rsvp" md-ink-ripple>
                                        <span class="ms-nav-label" >Telegram</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="writeWrapper">
            <h1>My Orders</h1>
            <hr></hr>
            <div style="width:100%; padding:20px" class="md-whiteframe-3dp" ng-repeat="product in vm.result | filter:searchText">
                <div class="orderId" layout="row" layout-align="space-between center">
                    <div>
                        <b>Placed On</b> : {{product.orderDate | date: "MMMM d, y, h:mm:ss a"}}<br>
                        <b>Order Id</b> : {{ product.transactionId }}
                    </div>
                    <span style="float:right"><md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Details</md-button></span>
                </div>
                
                <hr>
                
                <div style="width:100%;  padding:15px" layout="row">                
                    <div>
                        <img ng-src="{{ product.productImage }}" style="height:150px" alt="Image here" ><br>
                    </div>
                                        
                    <div style="width:400px; margin-left:30px">
                        <h2>{{ product.productName | characters:30 }}</h2><br>
                        
                        <div class="actionButtons">
                            <md-button class="md-raised">Return/Replace</md-button>
                            <md-button class="md-raised">Get Invoice</md-button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div layout="row" layout-align="space-between center">
                    <div>
                        <p>Status :</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p>Delivered On :</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr></hr>
                &nbsp;  
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</md-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an ng-include to include the elements, here your entire sidebar to all your pages. To do so you simply create another html page with the required sidebar and include it to the pages that need it.

Check it out here : [AngularJs docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)